# The Expectation of sum of square of random variables that are jointly t-distributed

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I need help in finding this expectation: $E[\sum_{i=1}^{M}X_i^2]$, where all $X_i$'s are jointly t-distributed (i.e. $\underline{X}\sim t(\underline{\mu},\underline{C},v)$). Where $\underline{\mu}$ is the mean vector, $\underline{C}$ is the covariance matrix and $v$ is the degrees of freedom.

Thank you very much in advance.

Best.

Comment: Where are you stuck? There are (potentially many more than) two ways to start playing around: 1) Expectation is linear so $E\left[\sum_{i=1}^M X_i^2 \right] = \sum_{i=1}^M E[X_i^2]$; or 2) since $\sum_{i=1}^M X_i^2 = \underline{X} \cdot \underline{X}$, you have $E\left[\sum_{i=1}^M X_i^2 \right] = E[\underline{X} \cdot \underline{X}]$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am stuck at the first one: $E[X_i^2]$.